# How can I create 2 workspaces in tkinter

Tags: python, programming-languages, tkinter

mi problem is this. I´ve already created a program with tkinter, but I want to run it twice in the same window, one in each side of the window. How can I do that??

The idea is to be able to compare the data from both programs so I want them to work separated.

Many thanks.

PD: I cannot post an image for you because of my reputation, sorry :(

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, what you need to do is put all of the logic behind creating and using a single workspace on a single `Frame` object.  Then you just need to create 2 Frames side-by-side -- Each one holding a "workspace".